# JQ links for labels + ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

So this is what i have:

```
<label for="prod1">
  <p>aaa</p>
</label>

<label for="prod2">
  <p>bbb</p>
</label>

<label for="prod3">
  <p>ccc</p>
</label>

<label for="prod4">
  <p>ddd</p>
</label>
```

I'm adding a href using JQ to all labels.  I can click two labels. How can I get a links of labels that was clicked and pass it to ajax ?

Comment: `label` tag has no `href` property , and is meant for form elements not to wrap `<p>`. html shown is invalid. Where is the code that manipulates labels?

Comment: why you can not use link label property OR <a href="path">aaa</a>

Comment: Hi Amol, thanks for info.. I just sort it out.. $('label').click(function(){var link = $(this).attr("href") console.log(link);

Comment: have you tried asp:LinkButton to redirect to ajax?

Comment: no... have a look on this one @Amol ... there's more specific desc...[link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14587014/values-from-radio-buttons-sum-function[/link]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Jquery** to get value that you clicked to label

```
$(function () {
    $("#some").click(function () {
        var x = document.getElementById('some').innerText;
        var y = document.getElementById('some').value;
        alert(x);
        alert(y);
    });
});
```

**page**

```
<label id="some" for="prod1">
      <p>aaa</p>
</label>
```