# values from radio buttons sum function

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to sum values from radio buttons.Two rows of divs and 2 radio buttons per row.
See link for more details:
    http://jsfiddle.net/HFuey/

JQ, I'm trying to use:

```
function recalculate() {
    var sum = 0;

    $("input[type=radio]:checked").each(function() {
        sum = parseFloat($(this).val();
    });

    $("#sum").html(sum.toFixed(2));
}

$("input[type=radio]").change(function() {
    recalculate();
});
```

is there any way to do it ? can I use href attribute too ?

Comment: Firstly there are several syntax errors with your fiddle and you've not selected a framework, so it doesn't work, here's a fixed one: http://jsfiddle.net/HFuey/2/. Secondly, all the options in the example have the same name, so only one can be selected anyway - there's no way to add up multiple ones because you can only select 1.

Comment: Other than a syntax error, do you have a specific problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you want

```
sum += parseFloat($(this).val());
```

so that it compiles (parenthesis) and that the value is incremented (`+=`).

Note also that you must also import jQuery in the fiddle and that you won't really have a sum if you have one group : only one radio button may be checked at a time.

So I suppose [you want this (link to fixed fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/dystroy/mA3QD/).